# Обработка запросов FLASK от разных пользователей

Tags: flask

код

```
app = Flask(__name__) 
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    sid = request.args['sid']
```

#сюда идет запрос с аргументом sid которой от разных пользователей разный. и далее в зависмости от sid идет обработка, но если зашло два пользовател с разным sid , то далее идет обработка у всех по тому sid который пришел позднее.....
Как сделать так, чтобы flask обрабатывал запрос раздельно от каждого пользователя....

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно приложить код обработки, хотя бы примерный. Особенно интересно каким образом передаётся sid в функцию-обработчик и используется ли в обработке многопоточность

Comment: Проблема решена.  @app.route ('/<route>')